# LoggedInSessionBean reference

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

Trying travelocity.com for SAML with wso2 and unable to show the SAML returned claim because of this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
Root Cause

javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
`
Jar file xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar is in lib folder under travelocity.com application but seems it is not able to read it.  

I saw that in the runtime tomcat : HTTP Session created without LoggedInSessionBean and the page getting the 500 error is using this reference:  <%@ page import="org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.bean.LoggedInSessionBean" %>
```

Any clue why getting this?

Comment: Can you please attach the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

This similar issue was already reported [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-6964) and can be solved  when copying [xercesimpl-2.8.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1) into /usr/share/tomcat7/lib in tomcat instance and restart the tomcat server.

Please try the workareound mentioned in the [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-6964)